# Send email using InfoBip

Tags: sendmail

Короче проблема в отправке емейла с Java через InfoBip.
Прошарил всю спецификацию и докумментацию, и смог сделать только вот такую штуку:

```
ContentType PLAIN_UTF8 = ContentType.create("text/plain", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setConnectionManager(new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager())
    .build();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://19v6md.api.infobip.com/email/2/send");
httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "App {myApiKey}");

MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
entityBuilder.addPart("from", new StringBody({MyEmailFromThatIsTrusted100%}, PLAIN_UTF8));
entityBuilder.addPart("to", new StringBody({MyEmailToOnGmailDotCom}, PLAIN_UTF8));
entityBuilder.addPart("subject", new StringBody("Mail subject", PLAIN_UTF8));
entityBuilder.addPart("text", new StringBody("Mail text", PLAIN_UTF8));
entityBuilder.addPart("html", new StringBody("<h1>Html body</h1><p>Rich HTML message body. 
                      </p>", PLAIN_UTF8));

httpPost.setEntity(entityBuilder.build());

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

И все время у меня приходит ответ 400 - сервис не понимает что от него хотят. Как я понимаю авторизация прошла отлично(сначала была 403, но я решил эту проблему заменив "аuthorization" на "Authorization"), а вот дальше сервис не понимает что от него хотят - то есть УРЛ("https://19v6md.api.infobip.com/email/2/send") не подходит и по этому урлу сервис не хочет отправлять емеил.

Пробовал менять урл на :

1. https://19v6md.api.infobip.com/email/1/send
2. https://api.infobip.com/email/1/send
3. https://api.infobip.com/email/2/send
   но код ответа не менялся.

Кто то знает как решить эту проблему?

Рs. Тех поддержка пока что молчит и другие примеры просто не работают.

Answer (score 0):

В общем кто будет стыкаться с подобной проблемой сразу пишите в поддержку. Решение стало очень неочевидным = у них просто не был зарегистрирован домен отправителя и даже то что значение почты {MyEmailFromThatIsTrusted100%}  находилось в категории Трастед не дало ничего. Сапорт просто зарегистрировал в системе тот домен и все заработало.